# how to automatically open the oracle form without prompting for jnlp frmservlet in edge browser

Tags: java, oracle

while opening a form in the Oracle-EBS application in the edge browser ,it is always prompting for jnlp frmservlet either for download or open the file. So how i can do this automatic without such prompting it should open the respective form.
I already done some settings in edge browser(edge) like Registry policy Appwed urls,allowed files,etc and also done settings in java configure application prompting for jnlp file---give allow all.
So even though done the above settings it is still prompting. Can you suggest what need to do further.Please hep me on this

it should not ask for download/open file ,automatically the file has to be open when we try to open it in Oracle EBS apllication .